# How do I get tkinter to work (in vim) and how do I get python-3.x running as my default python for linux?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, vim, linux-mint

From my understanding, tkinter comes pre-installed with python.  I can't, for the life of my, understand why every IDE I have tried to run tkinter on isn't recognizing tkinter as a library.

I have tried: 
`import tkinter as tk`
`import Tkinter as tk`
`import * from tkinter`
`from tkinter import *`
`import tkinter`
`import Tkinter`
and everything else in between...

The whole snipit I am trying to run:

```
 import Tkinter
 top = Tkinter.Tk()
 top.mainloop()
```

Whenever I try to run it in VIM the error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tktest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Tkinter
  File "usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 42, in <module>
    raise ImportError, str(msg) + ', please install the python-tk package'
ImportError: No module named_tkinter, please install the python-tk package

shell returned 1
```

Do I need vim to be running python3 in vim (which I thought was default) if so, how do I do that?

I have even tried to install tkinter like it says but I get this large error message:

```
ken@ken-HP-ENVY-Laptop-13-ah1xxx:~$ pip install Tkinter
Collecting Tkinter
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 795, in get_page
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/models.py", line 935, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/tkinter/
```

It looks like I am running python2.7 on my system by default and I don't know why... how do I get python3.7(or latest version) to be my default for my machine?

For the record, I am using Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia

Comment: it is standard to run Python 2 with command `python` and `python2` and `python2.7`, and Python 3 with `python3`, `python3.7`, `python3.8`, etc. The same with `pip`, `pip2`, `pip3`, `pip3.7`, etc. If you want to run script with some version of Python then you can use `shebang` in first line `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and set it executable `chmod a+x script.py` and then it will run as any program using automatically `python3`

Comment: error shows that your Python2 has no `Tkinter` - you may have to install it with `apt install python-tk`.

Comment: BTW: did you install fresh Mint 19.3 or you updated from older version? I have `Mint 19.3` updated from 19.2, updated from 19.1, updated from 18.0, updated from 17.0 and I have `Tkinter` in `Python 2` at start.

Comment: I will definitely try that! But yes, I installed fresh, not updated. It's strange because a lot of programs dont seem to work for me either like pycharm and intellij-idea. Pycharm worked for like a few minutes (had the same error trying to get tkinter going) and then it did this weird double window thing and wouldn't let me select other files in the sidebar. It only let me edit my code.

Comment: @furas while you are correct about the command names, expect this to change as python2 is deprecated

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I wouldn't change or remove `python2` (even if it is depercated) because system may still use `python2` to run some elements - especailly if I have the same system (with updates) since Mint 17.0 (2014)

Comment: @furas meant to indicate that python may come to mean python3, sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try running Python 3 in a [virtual environment](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/):

Open a terminal, go to your project directory and run 
`$ python3 -m venv venv`
which will create a virtual environment called `venv` in your project directory.

To activate it, go to your project directory and run `$ source venv/bin/activate`

Your bash prompt should now read `(venv) $` and any work you do will take place inside  a virtual environment.

Once you're done working inside the venv, you want to deactivate it. To deactivate, type `$ deactivate`

NOW, once your virtual environment is active you have a clean, package-free install of Python 3.x where x is whatever version you have installed and aliased to `python3`.

From in here, you can upgrade pip: `$ pip install -U pip`, re-install all the packages you want from a requirements.txt file: `$ pip install -r requirements.txt`, and install any other single packages you need with pip as usual.

*Anything you install in your virtual environment will **only** scope into your virtual environment*, so you can use this as a test bed, and destroy/rebuild as you see fit.  This is advantageous for a lot of reasons.

---

Once you've done this, try launching vim from inside your virtual environment, then try running your code from inside the virtual environment.  Once inside your venv, the only Python your terminal knows about is the one inside the venv. So it should default to that one.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Unfortunately, after doing these things I am still getting the error message `no module named 'Tkinter'` I tried both caps and non caps... I think it is strange because tkinter should be included with python.